# Reading signs like č ć đ š ž from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters

I have problems reading signs 'č', 'ć', 'đ', 'š', 'ž' from MySQL database.

I have tried few suggestions that I found on the internet, but none worked. I am looking for correct combination of charset in the database and in PHP file. So far I have always used UTF.

Comment: `mysql> CREATE DATABASE moo CHARACTER SET=utf8` didn't work for you, too?

Comment: No, it did not work, many people told me that it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'` before querying any data.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 7):

- Set table and db charset, collation, etc. to utf8_general_ci
- After establishing connection from php, be sure to do `SET NAMES UTF8`. That step is ***very important.***
- Make sure you saved all PHP files using utf-8 encoding (that was common cause several years ago)
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I'm from Slovenia, where we use these 'special chars', and believe me, this is our everyday problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this before reading

```
SET character_set_client='utf8'
SET character_set_results='utf8'
SET collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add simply in your PHP (in Writting and Reading):

```
$con = mysqli_connect(...);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

After having your table set as ut8 for default charset.