# Š, Č, Ć, Đ, Ž not appearing in Android application

Tags: php, android, character-encoding

I am having problem with showing these chars in my app. For example, in my MySQL database I have a row with text "Šauauaiaia" and in my app, in text field, it is shown like "null". If I substitute "Š" with other, "standard" char, everything is OK.

And for example "Ćća" is shown like "??a".

Could anyone tell me where should I make a change in order to fix this?

Here is my PHP script given.

```
<?php
$host = "xxx.xxx.xxx"; // host of MySQL server
$user = "xxx"; // MySQL user
$pwd = "xxx"; // MySQL user's password
$db = "xxx"; // database name



// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 



$sql = "Select id as iii,kategorija as ooo,naslov as nnn,datum as ddd,urlN as uuu from     vijesti where datum!='". $_POST["ustanova"]."' order by iii desc limit 0,20";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$rows[] = $row; 
}

// close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Reading signs like č ć đ š ž from MySql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057048/reading-signs-like-c-c-d-s-z-from-mysql-database)

I believe your question is answered here. Seems like a copy of the question; android shouldn't make it special.