# How to get local characters from MySql database on remote server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get local characters `č ž đ...` from MySql database.
On localhost the problem doesn't exists, but on remote server the local characters are missing.

Database and table collation is utf8_general_ci (according to one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057048/reading-signs-like-%C4%8D-%C4%87-%C4%91-%C5%A1-%C5%BE-from-mysql-database) )

my connection:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME.';charset=utf8_general_ci', DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

here I have the error - `Unknown character set`. Writing only `charset=utf8` the error is removing, but this doesn't help about local characters.

edit.php

```
include ("menut.php");
SET character_set_client = "utf8";  //line 12
SET character_set_results = "utf8";
SET collation_connection = "utf8_general_ci";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, content FROM  $table WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Here I have the error - `Unexpected T String` on line 12 (marked abowe).

Any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET character_set_client = "utf8";  //line 12
SET character_set_results = "utf8";
SET collation_connection = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Above are mysql commands, and you need to execute query to run these commands:

```
$db->query('SET character_set_client = "utf8"');
$db->query('SET character_set_results = "utf8"');
$db->query('SET collation_connection = "utf8_general_ci"');
```